# How can I get my AJAX response to go through on click event?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a ajax call I want to use on a form so the user doesn't have to reload the page but it just keeps loading. I have tried to change the post route but I haven't had any success. Can someone point me in the right direction. Here is my code:

```
HTML
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');

http.onload = () => {
    submit.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const alertMessage = document.querySelector('.alert');
        const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
        const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
        if (name === '' || email === '') {
                    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Name And Email Required';
                    console.log(name)
                } else {
                    alertMessage.innerHTML = 'Success! Someone will be in touch with you soon!'
                    // email.value = '';
                    // form.reset();
                }
    });
}

http.open('POST', '/index.html', true);
http.send();

FORM 
   <div class="contactform">
                <div class="alert"></div>
                <form action="/index.html" method="POST" class="form">
                    <input type="text" name='name' id='name' placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="email" name='email' id='email' placeholder="Email">
                    <textarea class="messages" name="messages" placeholder="Message...."></textarea>
                    <button class="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override form's onsubmit event to prevent submitting:

```
$("formSelector").bind('submit', function (e) {
    var isValid = someYourFunctionToCheckIfFormIsValid();
    if (!isValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_custom/url",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { "text": jQuery("#edit-body").html()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

By calling

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

You prevent synchronous postback from occurring.

UPDATE:
If you don't want to override form submit, maybe you could place your button outside of form tag (you can adjust position with css if necessary)?

Comment: Thanks for the try but I'm trying to let the response go through. It's still loading if I press submit. I thinks something is wrong with the file path. Thanks for your response through

Comment: If you can post URL to your website i'll make it work. Ya you have to change `my_custom/url` to `/index.html` I guess and it would send the AJAX.. and recieve data from `index.html` script and put it into the `#edit-body` aka  `<div id="edit-body">blah blah</div>`